# JavaScript - Getting no result

Tags: javascript

I have the following inputs:

```
<input class="form-control sampleLink" type="text" id="url" th:field="*{url}" th:value="*{url}" />
<input class="form-control sampleLink" type="number" id="port" th:field="*{port}" th:value="*{port}" /> 
<input class="form-control sampleLink" type="text" id="folder" th:field="*{folder}" th:value="*{folder}" />
```

I expect the next one to be auto-filled:

```
<input id="sampleLink" class="form-control" type="text" name="sampleLink" th:disabled="true" />
```

With this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready.(function() {
        $(".sampleLink").change(function() {
            var url = $("#url").val();
            var port = $("#port").val();
            var folder = $("#folder").val();

            $("#sampleLink").val('http://' + url + ':' + port + '/' + folder + '/*.txt');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get no result. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the code after the markup or are you initializing your code on dom ready?

Comment: This can have so many reasons to fail. What does the console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `});` at the end of the function.

Try this:

```
$(".sampleLink").change(function() {
var url = $("#url").val();
var port = $("#port").val();
var folder = $("#folder").val();

$("#sampleLink").val('http://' + url + ':' + port + '/' + folder + '/*.txt');});
```

Comment: I edited the post, completed the `<script>` section and corrected the syntax as per your suggestion. Still no good.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready.(function() {
        $(".sampleLink").change(function() {
            var url = $("#url").val();
            var port = $("#port").val();
            var folder = $("#folder").val();

            $("#sampleLink").val('http://' + url + ':' + port + '/' + folder + '/*.txt');
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: You forgot to call document

Comment: Alternatively to $(document).ready(function(){ ///Your code }); you can use $(function(){ ///your code here });

Comment: It seemed to be a missing or extra character somewhere. I replaced the `$(document).ready(function(){` line for some I had working on another page and all is good now! Thanks!